# PMF/PDF of f(X)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

given a random variable $X$ of which the PDF (if continuous) or PMF (if discrete) is known, how can I find the PDF/PMF of $X \mapsto f(X)$ ? Any help would be great.

Comment: For the discrete case, $\mathbb P(f(X)=k) = \sum\limits_{x:f(x)=k} \mathbb P(X=x)$

Comment: For the continuous case you may also need the summation if $f$ is not monotonic.  You certainly need to multiply by $|\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(k)|$ (see Wikipedia on [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar))

Comment: As an aside: in many cases of neat functions $f$ and known CDF of $X$ the CDF of $f(X)$ can be calculated. Then in the continuous case you can often find the PDF by taking the derivative of the CDF (if it has one of course). It is a good custom to try this first.